# A limit related to the Laplace constant

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Let $x\in (0,1)$,
$$
M(v,x) = 
\bigl(1+v^x\bigr)
\bigl(v^{1/x}-v\bigr)
+
x
\bigl(1+v^{1/x}\bigr)
\bigl(v^x-v\bigr)
$$
and let $v_0(x)$ be the root of $M(v,x)$ in $(0,1)$.  As $x \rightarrow 1$ this root (numerically) approaches a value $0.090776278\ldots$ which seems to be $(\alpha-1)/(\alpha+1)$ where $\alpha = 1.199678\ldots$ is the positive solution to $\coth(\alpha) = \alpha$, a quantity related the the Laplace limit constant (see [A033259](http://oeis.org/A033259) and the references therein).  I'm having problems proving this, any pointers would be appreciated.

edit: changed $[0,1]$ to $(0,1)$ as the location of the root of $M$: as mentioned in the original version of joriki's answer, both $0$ and $1$ are roots of $M$ (independent of $x$), so the former implies that $v_0$ is not well-defined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll assume you meant $(0,1)$ instead of $[0,1]$, as both $0$ and $1$ are also roots, independent of $x$.

[Wolfram|Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=series%20for%20%281%2bv%5Ex%29%28v%5E%281/x%29%E2%88%92v%29%2bx%281%2bv%5E%281/x%29%29%28v%5Ex%E2%88%92v%29%20at%20x=1) provides the series expansion at $x=1$:

$$M(v,1+\epsilon)=\epsilon^2v\log v\left(2+2v+\log v-v\log v\right)+O\left(\epsilon^3\right)\;.$$

For $\epsilon\to0$, the root must converge to a root of the expression in parentheses. Your transformation $v=(\alpha-1)/(\alpha+1)$ [transforms](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2%2b2v%2blog%20v%E2%88%92v%20log%20v%20where%20v=%28x-1%29/%28x%2b1%29) this into

$$\frac2{\alpha+1}\left(2\alpha+\log\frac{\alpha-1}{\alpha+1}\right)\;.$$

Again the expression in parentheses must vanish, so

$$
\log\frac{\alpha-1}{\alpha+1}=-2\alpha\;,
\\
\frac{\alpha-1}{\alpha+1}=\mathrm e^{-2\alpha}\;,
\\
\mathrm e^{\alpha}(\alpha-1)=\mathrm e^{-\alpha}(\alpha+1)\;,
\\
\alpha\left(\mathrm e^{\alpha}-\mathrm e^{-\alpha}\right)=\mathrm e^{\alpha}+\mathrm e^{-\alpha}\;,
\\
\alpha=\coth\alpha\;.
$$

The negative root leads to $v\notin(0,1)$, so the root we want is the positive one.

Comment: Oh, that's pretty joriki, very pretty.  Many thanks.

Comment: @n00b: You're welcome.